# Proper way to use execlp and execvp while reporting exit status in C

Tags: c, fork, child-process, execvp, waitpid

I'm a student studying C and how to create processes using fork()
Can you please explain what is the difference between these two codes because I've tried the both and they didn't work as expected.

```
child = fork();
child1 = fork();
if (child == 0 && child1 == 0){//Parent}
else if (child > 0 && child1 == 0){//first child}
else if (child == 0 && child1 > 0){//second child}
else {third child}
```

is this is the right way to create the children or is it the one below?

```
child = fork();
if (child == 0)
{
    child1 = fork();
    if (child1 == 0)
    {// grandchild
    }
    else
    {//child
    }
}
else 
{//parent
}
```

These are examples written by me on what confused me.
Here's the code i'm having trouble with

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    pid_t child;
    pid_t child1;
    // at least, there should be 3 arguments
    // 2 for the first command, and the rest for the second command
    //printf("%d\n", argc);
    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s cmd1 cmd1_arg cmd2 [cmd2_args ..]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    child = fork();
    //pid_t child1;
    // TODO
    if (child < 0)
    {
        perror("fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (child == 0)//child1
    {
        //printf("exited=%d exitstatus=%d\n", WIFEXITED(exitStatus), WEXITSTATUS(exitStatus));
        child1 = fork();

        if (child1 == 0)//grandchild
        {
            execlp(argv[1],argv[1],argv[2],NULL); 
            perror("execlp()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        else //first child
        {
            int status1;
            waitpid(child1, &status1, 0);
            printf("exited=%d exitstatus=%d\n", WIFEXITED(status1), WEXITSTATUS(status1));
            execvp(argv[3], (argv + 3));
            perror("execlp()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else//parent
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        printf("exited=%d exitstatus=%d\n", WIFEXITED(status), WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm able to get the code to work as intended but i'm confused on how to use WIFEXITED and WEXITSTATUS.
My code output when I run this code is

```
execlp(): No such file or directory
Makefile
exited=1 exitstatus=0
```

And the right output is:

```
execlp(): No such file or directory
Makefile
exited=1 exitstatus=1
exited=1 exitstatus=0
```

Arguments used in this test case

```
cal -3 ls Makefile
```

Why am I missing the second exit print?

Comment: You have the comment `if (child == 0 && child1 == 0){//Parent}` — that's wrong; the parent has both PID values non-zero.  The process with both PID values zero is the grandchild.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry that was a typo, I do understand what you are saying but I'm not sure what is the best way to implement solving the problem I have on hand. I want to run two exe commands and print the exit status. Can you give me an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your sample command line is puzzling.  You say `cal -3 ls Makefile`, and your usage message says `Usage: %s cmd1 cmd1_arg cmd2 [cmd2_args ..]`.  Assuming your program is called `cal` (note that there is, at least on many systems, a standard program called `cal` — try `cal 9 1752`), then your `cmd1` is `-3`, the argument to it is `ls`, and the `cmd2` is `Makefile`, which is not very conventional.  I'd expect something more like `./cal ls -l cat Makefile` as an invocation.  Would we be correct in assuming you want `cmd1 cmd1arg` run and completed before `cmd2 [cmd2arg ...]` is run?

Answer (score 1):

Your first two code snippets **are not same** at all.

First case,

[image]

Second case,

[image]

Comment: I now understand what this code means and I was able to fix most of my problems. The only problem I'm still facing is how to control which exe command runs first? It doesn't seem to work if I flip them for some reason